# Is there a way to check If library is still loaded into the process, using perl

Tags: java, perl, dll

I had a task to unload a DLL from a container. Now I need to write a test for my code using Perl. My question is:

Is there a way to check if library (`.dll` or `.so`) has been loaded/unloaded into the process (`java.exe` in my case), using Perl standard functionality?

Comment: Are you working on Windows? How are you unloading the DLL?

Comment: Hi Borodin, I work on Windows and Linux. library is written on c++ and is being loaded by the java code. Wrapper classes are generated by swig. I have written custom class loader to load necessary classes. Dll is being unloaded when all objects of classes loaded by the class loader are garbage collected. More precisely my task is to unload war file on the fly(with all underling jar-s dll/so-s etc.., to upgrade without restarting container). I need to check whether library is still loaded into the java.exe or not using perl standard features, after war file deletion from webapps dir.